# Javascript Variable Increase

Tags: javascript

I am a noob to javascript and and programming really and I just want to know what I am doing wrong. Im sure this is a really simple question but I have no idea why this isn't working. According to research online I'm doing everything correctly.

```
var varname  = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 74) {
        varname++;
        console.log(varname);
    }
}
```

Everytime I press "j" I want to increase my variable, but console log shows a consistent 1 and doesn't go any higher. What can I do Thanks for the help. The key press event works fine, the number just wont increase upon the keypress. Thanks again

Comment: Declare the variable outside your event handler.

Comment: No difference Thanks Though

Comment: This is not your full code, is it? Where is the signature of your event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just declare like this:

```
var varname  = 0;

function keyPress(e){
  if(e.which == 74) {
     varname++;
     console.log(varname);
   }
}
```

In this case, your variable will keep it's previous value, and it will increment.

Comment: Does this really works? I mean... to which element is this function associated as an event handler?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell, but I presume you're trying for something like this:

```js
var jCounter = 0

document.getElementById('keycheck')
  .addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    if (evt.which === 74) {
      console.log("Yup, that's a 'j' alright.")
      jCounter++
      document.getElementById('jcounter').innerHTML = jCounter
    }
  })
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keycheck" placeholder="I really like j's...">
<span id="jcounter">0</span>
```